# Negative chat id in log file of telegram bot

Tags: php-telegram-bot

I have a Telegram bot and I save all user activity in a log file. When I checked the log file, I found a user with a negative chat ID `-107606558`. Is this normal?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If the chat is a group, the chat id is negative. If it is a single person, then positive.

Comment: any references?

Comment: I second the call for references - I doubt that my bot has been used in only 10 groups but by 670+ unique users. However, I couldn't create a counterexample group.

Comment: seems its correct: https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/issues/661